# How do you add input from user into list in Python

Tags: python, list

```
print ('This is your Shopping List')          
firstItem = input('Enter 1st item: ')         
print (firstItem)             
secondItem = input('Enter 2nd item: ')           
print (secondItem)
```

How do I make a list of what the user has said then print it out at the end when they have finished?

Also how do I ask if they have added enough items to the list? And if they say no then it will print out the list of items already stored.

Thanks, I'm new to this so I don't really know.

Comment: `list.append(variable)`

Comment: If you are new, spend some time reading the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/).

Answer (score 18):

```
shopList = [] 
maxLengthList = 6
while len(shopList) < maxLengthList:
    item = input("Enter your Item to the List: ")
    shopList.append(item)
    print shopList
print "That's your Shopping List"
print shopList
```

Answer (score 7):

code below allows user to input items until they press enter key to stop:

```
In [1]: items=[]
   ...: i=0
   ...: while 1:
   ...:     i+=1
   ...:     item=input('Enter item %d: '%i)
   ...:     if item=='':
   ...:         break
   ...:     items.append(item)
   ...: print(items)
   ...: 

Enter item 1: apple

Enter item 2: pear

Enter item 3: #press enter here
['apple', 'pear']

In [2]:
```